# how to Auto Create Invoice & Auto Validate Invoice when sale order gets confirmed in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

'How to Auto transfer delivery/picking while confirming sale quotation.
Auto Create Invoice & Auto Validate Invoice when sale order gets confirmed in odoo.'

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

Just ***override*** the method under **CONFIRM** button of ***sale.order*** and write the logic of creating invoice and validate it.

*Example:*

```
def action_confirm(self):
    """Your Logic"""
```

**Solution 2:**

Use Odoo's **Automated Actions** on record update and run your custom python script.

Comment: Don't forget to return this in the confirm function `return super().action_confrim()`